# Not responding to the click of the partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a parent view and a partial view in it.

The partial view is 2 pseudo buttons - thumb up and thumb down. A paragraph with classes assigned.

It is not responding to a click on either thumb. Nor is it getting into the 2 functions that should be executed on 'ready'.

It gets into the jQuery in the partial view when rendered. However not completely as I do not see all the console logs or alerts that I put in.

I get the alert and console log for the 'ready' function but not for the other functions. It does not execute the 2 console.log lines which reference the Model properties which are boolean and have each a value of false.

[image]

I get this error: jQuery.Deferred exception: False is not defined ReferenceError: False is not defined.

But it does not seem to be my custom code.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

The partial view has a model where by I have properties I want to use 2 booleans as well has integers.

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class LikeOrDislikeVM
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        public int DisLikeCount { get; set; }
        public bool LikeDisabled { get; set; }
        public bool DisLikeDisabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Not sure if that is the reason. I show the model coming in and false is in lowercase coming in so that meets the JavaScript requirement.

[image]

The parent view that has the partial view in it (not showing all the code):

```
        @{
            // Create the variable form the LikeOrDislikeVM model.
            var likeOrDislikeVM = new GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM();

            // Set the properties on the variable - most from the parent model.
            likeOrDislikeVM.BlogId = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId;
            likeOrDislikeVM.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
            likeOrDislikeVM.LikeCount = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.LikeCount;
            likeOrDislikeVM.DisLikeCount = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeCount;
            likeOrDislikeVM.LikeDisabled = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.LikeDisabled;
            likeOrDislikeVM.DisLikeDisabled = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeDisabled;
        }

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Partial("_BlogLikeAndDislike", likeOrDislikeVM)
            </div>
        </div>
```

The partial view:

```
    @model GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM

   <style>
    .fa {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .fa:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

   .my-size {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>

 @* Use the values that were passed via a model. *@
 <div class="row">
<p><span class="blogLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.LikeCount</span> <span class="my-size"> | </span><span class="blogDisLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-down"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.DisLikeCount</span></p>
 </div>

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Here at document ready');
    console.log('Here at document ready');

    console.log(@Model.LikeDisabled);
    console.log(@Model.DisLikeDisabled);

    SetLike(@Model.LikeDisabled);
    SetDisLike(@Model.DisLikeDisabled);

    $('.blogLike').on('click', function () {
        alert('Here at like');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SetBlogLikeOrDisLike", "BlogPublished")',
            data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model, likeOrDislikeIndicator: "L"},
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetBlogLikeOrDisLike for a Like! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    });

    $('.blogDisLike').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SetBlogLikeOrDisLike", "BlogPublished")',
            data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model, likeOrDislikeIndicator: "D"},
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetBlogLikeOrDisLike for a DisLike! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    });

    function SetLike(disabledSwitch) {
        alert('Here at SetLike');
        $(".blogLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        //if (disabledSwitch == false )
        //{
        //    $(".blogLike").color('green');
        //}
    }

    function SetDisLike(disabledSwitch) {
        alert('Here at SetDisLike');
        $(".blogDisLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        //if (disabledSwitch == false) {
        //    $(".blogDisLike").color('green');
        //}
    }
});
</script>
```

---

After surrounding the model properties with ticks. The code now executes but the boolean values are False instead of false. Yet the model screen shot shows them as false. JavaScript needs them to be false. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: According to the first screen shot, you have a variety of JavaScript errors to be addressed.  Any one of which could be stopping the code from executing further.

Comment: David...yeah I see those but don't know how to resolve them as they seem library errors. I removed my 2 .on click functions and just left my 2 set custom functions to see if it was my custom code. Still does not execute the console.log lines or enter either of those simple custom functions.

Comment: The 2 console lines reference the model properties which are boolean and have each a value of false. And I get that: jQuery.Deferred exception: False is not defined ReferenceError: False is not defined.

Comment: David...getting closer. I had to add ticks around the model properties. Such as         console.log('@Model.LikeDisabled'); and SetLike('@Model.LikeDisabled'); The code now executes. However, the problem is that the value is False not false. Yet the Model itself has the properties as false. JavaScript needs them as false. I included the screen shot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the False to false and True to true, I added const

```
const False = false, True = true;
```

and passed them to the function without ticks.

I now get false and true and the code executes properly.

```
SetLike(@Model.LikeDisabled);
SetDisLike(@Model.DisLikeDisabled);
```